# Issue during validation and render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form

I have an issue when submitting a form.

I have two models, `:service` and `:booking`. For a service, there is a button:

```
<%= link_to "Book Now", new_booking_path(service_id: @service.id) %>
```

When this button is clicked it takes the user to the `_form.html.erb` where they can book the service. This is the simplified booking form:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@booking) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label "Booking Date" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
    <%= f.text_field :time, :id => "timepicker" %>
    <%= f.input :address, label: "Address" %>
    <%= f.input :postcode, label: "Postcode" %>
    <%= f.input :suburb, label: "Suburb" %>

    <%= f.input :servicetitle, :input_html => { :value => @service.title } %>
    <%= f.input :serviceprice, :input_html => { :value => @service.price } %>
    <%= f.input :servicetime, :input_html =>  { :value => @service.time } %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I have three fields, `:servicetitle`, `:serviceprice` and `:servicetime`.

These fields get their input values from the `@service.id` value passed through the link_to button. I am able to access the records like `@service.title` using this instance variable in the `bookings_controller`:

```
@service = Service.find_by_id(params[:service_id])
```

The problem I am having is that if one of the field validation fails (say the `:date` field), then the user gets redirected back to the `_form.html.erb` and I get the error

> NoMethodError in Bookings#create
>   
>   undefined method `title`

I would also get the errors:

> undefined method `price`

and:

> undefined method `time`

I think this is because Rails doesn't have access to the `@service` instance variable anymore?

How am I able to fix this when a validation fails?

**Edit**:

Create method in bookings controller:

```
def create
    @booking = current_user.bookings.build(bookings_params)
    if @booking.save
        BookingMailer.form_confirmation(@booking).deliver
        redirect_to @booking
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: How is service implemented in relation to booking? What are the input fields?

Comment: @vee A service belongs to a booking, and a booking has many services. My form works correctly, except when it renders the form on error, the `@service` instance variable seems to get destroyed

Comment: Right, your create method does not define `@service` which is why you're losing the values. Can you post your controller `create` action?

Comment: @vee have updated my question with the create method

Comment: Are you letting your users create services during booking? Should you rather use a "select option"/dropdown of available services so that you can easily uniquely identify your service in `BookingsController#create`. Is this Rails 5?

Comment: @vee No, the services are already created, they just book them. That is a good idea actually, i've just tried to implement a dropdown and it is probably a better option. And yes I'm using rails 5. Although is there any way to still keep the instance variable on render? As I already have that all setup

Comment: Yes once you have select option, you can pass the service id as the value which you grab in your `create` action with `params['service_id']`. You then use it to initialize `@service` as `@service = Service.where(id: params['service_id'])`.

Comment: @vee I have tried but do not want to do it this way (it messes up other parts of my app). Is there no way I can keep the render and the `@service` instance variable?

Comment: It messes up other parts of your app when adding `@service` to your `create` action? How so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't passed the service id again to create method so probably it won't be getting the params[:service_id] in create.

Add a hidden field in form with the service_id and then check.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:service_id,@service.id) %>
```

Comment: I cant believe it but this actually worked! thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is down to the fact that in your create method you have not assigned anything to the @service variable, in your new method you are instantiating the @service variable (at least I assume you are as you are not getting an error when you go to the 'action'), but you are not doing it in the create action.

When you go to the create action, the whole request cycle starts from scratch, meaning anything you did in the 'new' action is gone.
When you have an error, your create action goes to the else block and runs `render 'new'` which renders the `new.html.erb` template from scratch, if you are rendering a template with an @service variable, then you will need to define that variable in the action before you render the template. eg `@service = Service.new` or `@service = Service.find(params[:service_id])`. Otherwise, your template is calling the `title` `price` and `time` methods on a `nil` object.

Comment: Thanks and yes i understand what's happening, although even If i include the line `@service = Service.find(params[:service_id])` in the create method I still get the error

Comment: The exact same error? can you post the error you get when you are setting `@service`, as well as the code from the create method with `@service` being set, and your log when you send the create request